# How was the formulas for x,y,z derived from Perspective Projection Formula (stereo vision)

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-vision

[Perspective Projection Formula Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iuN5.png)

Hello, I'm learning some formula in relation to computer vision and came across this. How was the formula for x, y, and z formed?

Here's the referenced video (4:25 for time stamp): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hUVyDabn1Mg

Perspective Projection Formula:

$$(u^{}_{l},v^{}_{l}) = 
(f^{}_{x}\frac{x}{z} + o^{}_{x},f^{}_{y}\frac{y}{z} + o^{}_{y} )
$$

$$ (u^{}_{r},v^{}_{r}) = 
(f^{}_{x}\frac{x - b}{z} + o^{}_{x},f^{}_{y}\frac{y}{z} + o^{}_{y} )
$$

Formula for x, y, and z are as follows (from video):

$$
x = \frac{b(u^{}_{l} - o^{}_{x})}{(u^{}_{l} - u^{}_{r})}
$$

$$
y = \frac{bf^{}_{x}(v^{}_{l} - o^{}_{y})} {f^{}_{y}(u^{}_{l} - u^{}_{r})}
$$

$$
z = \frac{bf^{}_{x}} {(u^{}_{l} - u^{}_{r})}
$$

Comment: From the formula for $u_l$ and $u_r$ you get a linear system for $x,z$. Then use the obtained value for $z$ in the equation for the (identical) second component.